# I sent out a payment over a day ago and it's still not confirmed

Tags: electrum, unconfirmed-transactions, payment

https://blockchain.info/tx/3b047ef34fcd283ce57868dedb80eb239970ded1aeb10c0fe3a39360dc822056

https://blockchain.info/tx/2a774b4a29a498f95aeb8fd256c36404118fce1157aea976a3fcfe0f29a6918c

Electrum won't let me overwrite the payment with a higher fee either. Any Ideas?

EDIT: I'm using electrum and it wont let me send out another transaction without the "funds" in the wallet which are still unconfirmed. Is there a way to resend the transaction with a higher fee from a website or another wallet? Or is there a way to cancel the entire unconfirmed transaction so I can resend the payment?

Sidenote: There's not enough bitcoin in my wallet to send out a CPFP.

Comment: Related: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/51511/broadcast-a-signed-transaction

Answer (score 2):

The fees you included are quite low indeed.

According to [Bitcoinfees](https://bitcoinfees.21.co/), and [Bitcoinexchangerate](http://bitcoinexchangerate.org/fees) the current recommended fee/byte is around 160-168 Satoshis, implying a median transaction fee (around 226-byte transaction) of about 40K Satoshi. In your case, you are paying around 50 Satoshi/byte, 116K Satoshi per transaction. The sources differ in how many blocks will take for a transaction with this fee ratio to be published, from 6 blocks to way more than a day.

What can you do? You can either wait until both transactions get confirmed. Wait until them get pruned from the nodes mempool and resubmit them with a higher fee, or create a new transaction spending from the last one using a [CPFP](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/5g1ge3/your_trasaction_stuck_as_unconfirmed_use_a/) approach.

**Child pays for parent (CPFP)**

Basically what you do is to create a new transaction spending from one that is already unconfirmed, and add a high fee to that new transaction. By doing so, you incentivize a miner to include that last transaction in the blockchain, having to include the previous one also.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm using electrum and it wont let me send out another transaction without the "funds" in the wallet which are still unconfirmed. Is there a way to resend the transaction with a higher fee from a website or another wallet?

Comment: Not really. You will need to modify the transaction in order to add a higher fee, and by doing so the signature will not match. Moreover, the ID will change and it will be treated as double spend, as long as your old transaction is still in the mempool of the network nodes. If you have access to the keys of your address (if you can export them from Electrum), you can use them with bitcoind or bitcoin-qt for example to build a CPFP that will do the trick.