# Are the outputs of an unconfirmed transaction part of the global UTXO pool?

Tags: transactions, unconfirmed-transactions, utxo

Well basically that. If a transaction is in the memory pool, that is, it is not yet in a block but nodes and miners know about it and validated it, Can I send another transaction that double-spends the outputs? that is, are the outputs considered unspent?

Comment: It is not clear to me whether you are suggesting to doublespend the inputs or the outputs of the unconfirmed transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that there are two UTXO under your control, `U1` and `U2`.

You use `U1` and `U2` to create a transaction `T1` that would create `U3` when confirmed. `U1` and `U2` therefore are *inputs* of the unconfirmed transaction `T1` and `U3` is an output of `T1`.

`U1` and `U2` are unspent, however another transaction `T2` spending either or both of them would be considered a doublespend by any node that knew about `T1` before.

Meanwhile, until `T1` is confirmed, `U3` is not part of the UTXO pool. Since the transaction is yet unconfirmed, the newly created output doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 2):

The transactions are considered spent from the nodes that already have the transaction in the `mempool`, that is, if you try to double-spend the transaction, they will reject the new one. However, if the transaction ends up not being included in a block, they will be dropped from the `mempool` after a certain time. After that, you will be able to create a new transaction that spends the same `UTXOs`, since from that point on it won't be considered double-spending.

Comment: Thanks. How much would taht time be? Because I sent a tx with such a low fee that it's taking too much time to get into a block and my last hope is for it to get dropped from the mempool of the nodes.

Comment: It could last a while, I don't know exactly how much, honestly. However, if you are in a hurry, you can use the solution from this answer: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/51524/i-sent-out-a-payment-over-a-day-ago-and-its-still-not-confirmed/51534#51534